# How to update foreign keys with new values properly?

Tags: flask, web, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I've been trying to build a web to check student attendance. I'm aiming to get a list of students of a classroom on a webpage

User class:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
occupation = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
year = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

classroom = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classroom.id'))
posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"User('{self.email}', '{self.name}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

Classroom class:

```
class Classroom(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(80))

    users = db.relationship('User', backref='user', lazy=True)



    @classmethod
    def get_classroom(cls):
        classroom_list = Classroom.query.all()
        return [(classroom.id, classroom.name) for classroom in classroom_list]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Classroom('{self.name}', '{self.description}')"
```

However, as classrooms were not created at first, no foreign keys were actually given to students in regard to their classrooms, then set as Null by default.

So, I was going to update the foreign keys by picking out one selection from a drop-down with HTML only but I could not figure out a proper solution and decided to try it with another method. A new form for that is now created and then it seems alright on a webpage. but the code isn't actually working well internally and posing some problems.

Form:

```
class SelectClassroomForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name')
    year = StringField('Year')
    classroom = SelectField('Classroom',
                            choices=Classroom.get_classroom(),
                            )
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

Trying to update foreign keys:

```
@app.route("/students", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def students():
    form = SelectClassroomForm()
    students = User.query.filter(User.year != "I'm not a Student")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        students.classroom = form.classroom.data[0]
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Successfully Added classroom info to students', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('students'))
    else:
        flash("something's wrong", 'danger')
    return render_template('students.html', students=students, form=form)
```

I'm not sure whether it is the code above or HTML code down below that is stopping me from updating the keys..

HTML Code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Student List</h2>
    <div class="content-section">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                        <th> Name </th>
                        <th> Year </th>
                        <th> Classroom </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for student in students %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ student.name }} </td>
                    <td> {{ student.year }} </td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                            {{ form.classroom(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('students') }}">Update</a>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

(sorry about the uncolored codes by the way I was trying to find out how to but failed on my own page)

Anyways, Here the webpage shows the list of students as it was supposed to be but when I click on the update button, that's when the problem turns up. How can I solve it and then successfully update students' info with new foreign keys? Any help will be much appreciated Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Instead of simply displaying "something's wrong", have your application write diagnostic information (including complete error messages and stack trace output) to a log file and then [edit] your question to include the relevant details.

Comment: There was no error message actually nor trace output other than 200, so, sadly, no more relevant details couldn't be drawn out..

Comment: Immediately before calling `flash` to display "something's wrong", `print` the form object (or dump `repr(form)` to a file). The form object should contain information on why the validation failed.

Comment: I think with the update button the form is ignored and you send another GET request. Therefore `validate_on_submit` will fail because it is not a POST request. Encapsulate the update button in the form using `<button type="submit">` to use the method and action parameters of the form.